# minted creating garbage output on PDF file

Tags: minted, syntax, python

Good Day,

I'm using texlive 2013 which I updated today 20JULY13. When I attempt to compile my LaTeX file using only the most basic minted statements

```
\begin{minted}{c}
Test
\end{minted}
```

results in my compiled PDF file to contain:

```
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{makeatletter}
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{@}\PY{n}{reset}\PY{
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{let}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{@}\PY{n}{ul}\PY
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{let}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{@}\PY{n}{bc}\PY
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{@}\PY{n}{tok}\PY{er
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{@}\PY{n}{toks}\PY{e
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{@}\PY{n}{tok}\PY{p}{\PYZob{}}\PY{err}{\PYZsh
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{@}\PY{k}{do}\PY{err
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{@}\PY{n}{it}\PY{p}{\PYZob{}}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PY}\PY{err}{\PYZsh{}}\PY{l+m+mi
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{expandafter}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{expandafter}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{expandafter}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{expandafter}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{expandafter}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PYZti}\PY{p}{\PYZob{}}\PY{err}{
\PY{o}{\PYZpc{}} \PY{k}{for} \PY{n}{compatibility} \PY{n}{with} \PY{n}{earlier} \PY{n
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PYZat}\PY{p}{\PYZob{}}\PY{err}{
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PYZlb}\PY{p}{\PYZob{}[\PYZcb{}}
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{def}\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{PYZrb}\PY{p}{\PYZob{}]\PYZcb{}}
\PY{err}{\PYZbs{}}\PY{n}{makeatother}
```

Anyone else experienced this? If so did you find a conflicting package or a logical reason why this is suddenly happening? Thank You.

Comment: This work for me: `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{minted}\begin{document}\begin{minted}{c}Test\end{minted}Test\end{document}`

Comment: Please, add a minimal example.

Comment: With no MWE this is unclear, I'm afraid